# Snowflake Metadata has weird table names

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am seeing something weird in a Snowflake database I'm working with. Our table names in the metadata are different than the actual table names.

For example, we have a table named

TABLE_NAME

but if I query the metadata for metadata about TABLE_NAME it comes back null. The metadata for TABLE_NAME appears to be stored under TABLE_NAME_1557893E-69ED-4225-9A54-C836977F01A8

Has anyone here had any experience with why this might be happening?

Comment: `if I query the metadata for metadata about TABLE_NAME it comes back null` - please provide the actual query structure  and describe how tables are created - most likely the suffix is added by some tooling to ensure table name to be globally unique

Comment: try this `select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = upper('MY_TABLE') ` ?